# Нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

«О том, как привести дороги в нормативное состояние, куда сдавать арматуру(,) нам рассказал директор завода Иван Иванов».

Верна ли запятая перед «нам»? Склоняюсь к тому, что она нужна.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Запятая нужна. Она закрывает одно из придаточных (изъяснительных) предложений.

Главное предложение: *О том нам рассказал директор завода Иван Иванов*.

*О том* (о чём?), *как привести, куда сдавать, нам рассказал...*